# Canceling Tachanun for the balance of a month

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tachanun, simchah-joy-happiness

Based on the [premise](https://books.google.com/books?id=p2qC-G9wR1EC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=tachanun%20half%20the%20month&source=bl&ots=HRELTGNtku&sig=ft4pAKebmevRfglRtKjWaCV0fyc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY48Pm8-3dAhXSq1kKHR1kDQcQ6AEwBnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=tachanun%20half%20the%20month&f=false) that we don't say Tachanun for the rest of a month when there are already a majority of days on which we don't say Tachanun (as stated in the Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 131,7 about Nissan), would this apply in a case where the majority days of a month have Tachanun canceled for non-"holiday" reasons?

If, in a community, a man gets [married](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/tues_02_07_12/) on the 2nd of Cheshvan and goes to the minyan on that day and every day thereafter, and then another man gets married on the 9th and goes to shul, and throw in a [bris](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/mon_02_06_12/) on the 17th and 18th, then most of the month has no Tachanun (you probably need fewer because of Shabbat, but I'm making sure). Would that congregation, for that year, stop saying Tachanun for the rest of Cheshvan?

Comment: Why was this excellent question downvoted?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's to do with being inherent in the month.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this just proves that skipping Tachanun the last few days of Tishrei isn't traditional Judaism (indeed it was invented quite recently)

Comment: Your source says "it is as if the whole month was comprised of holy days" why would that apply here?

Comment: Shabbat is not a day for tachanun, so it is not included in the count.  There are years where with Shabbat SIvan has most days not tachanun because of shavuot, yet we still say rest of time.

Answer (score 4):

It seems from this story that if an individual doesn't say Tachanun for most of the month for a private reason (with exception of Nissan where everyone doesn't say Tachanun for most of the month and therefore the whole month) one still does Tachanun at any given opportunity when one can

Bava Metzia 59b

> אימא שלום דביתהו דר"א אחתיה דר"ג הואי מההוא מעשה ואילך לא הוה שבקה ליה לר"א למיפל על אפיה ההוא יומא ריש ירחא הוה ואיחלף לה בין מלא לחסר איכא דאמרי אתא עניא וקאי אבבא אפיקא ליה ריפתא אשכחתיה דנפל על אנפיה אמרה ליה קום קטלית לאחי
>   When Rabban Gamliel excommunicated Rabbi Eliezer Ima Shalom (Rabbi Eliezers wife and Rabban Gamliels sister) would stand by him and didn't allow R' Eliezer to say Tachanun. One day she thought it was Rosh Chodesh on the 30th day of the month when it was not yet until the 31st day* She did not attend to Rabbi Eliezer and he said Tachanun and as a result Rabban Gamliel died.

So the whole month Rabbi Eliezer didn't say Tachanun yet as soon as he found an oppertunity he said right on the last day of the month. I assume that he was Patur because of Pikuach nefesh and that his case does not differ from those whom are Patur for lesser reasons e.g aveil Choson Baal bris.

---

*(Rashi:סבורה היתה שיהא החדש חסר וקבוע ביום ל' ולא יפול ביום החדש על פניו והיה מלא ולא נקבע עד יום שלשים ואחד ולא נזהרה בו ביום ל' ונפל על פניו:)